Calculating Confidence Intervals for Odds Ratios Based Only on Odds Ratio and Total Sample Size
I'm running a meta-analysis, and many studies report only the total sample size and odds ratio, which complicates calculating the sampling variances. I could use the odds ratio, total sample size, and p-values to determine the sampling variances (conv.wald function). However, the studies either do not report p-values or provide only approximate values.
Is there a way to calculate the confidence intervals using just the OR and total sample?
I've written the function below, but I'm not entirely sure if it's correct assuming se_or <- sqrt(1/n).
my_func <- function(or, n) {
  log_or <- log(or)
  se_or <- sqrt(1/n)
  z <- qnorm((1 + .95)/2)
  log_or_ci_lower = log_or - z*se_or
  log_or_ci_upper = log_or + z*se_or
  ci_lower = exp(log_or_ci_lower)
  ci_upper = exp(log_or_ci_upper)
  return(list(or, ci_lower, ci_upper))
}


I've flagged as a duplicate, but in short the standard error of the log OR is not sqrt(1/n).  In the case where it is estimated by the 2x2 table $\left(\begin{array}{c c}a&b\c&d\end{array}\right) $, the se of the log OR is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}}$.  With just the OR and the sample size you can't calculate this well enough, you would need another piece of information eg the total number of positives.

@shira I just posted an answer in the duplicated thread (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/585610/calculate-se-of-odds-ratio-for-meta-analysis-without-95-ci-or-p-value) in addition to the existing answer, hopefully it might be useful to you.
